# Getting "java.lang.SecurityException"

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I have a project in which I have these jars:

- bcprov-ext-jdk15-141.jar
- bcprov-jdk15-141.jar
- bcmail-jdk14-136.jar

**Problem**

Now I am using `itextpdf-5.5.9.jar` with `bcprov-jdk15on-1.50.jar` to generate password protected PDF but the problem is if I remove old bc jars it works fine but I have other code dependencies which uses previous 3 jars.

So if I keep these old jar I get

> java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package.

I think these jars are conflicting can anyone suggest some solution.

Comment: If you are using maven can you please share the POM ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven, just use the following dependency and it will automatically add the required org.bouncycastle » bcpkix-jdk15on 1.49 and     org.bouncycastle » bcprov-jdk15on 1.49 automatically.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.9</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using maven then try using 1.49 org.bouncycastle jars.

Comment: I tried only itextpdf.5.5.9 only in my maven project and it is not encrypting pdf nor it is throwing any error but if I use bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.50.jar also, I get the above error.

Comment: and if I remove these three jars bcprov-ext-jdk15-141.jar
bcprov-jdk15-141.jar
bcmail-jdk14-136.jar it encrypts pdf properly

Comment: no problem is still same I cant remove previous jars because my project have other dependencies on those jars so need a solution through which I can keep all the jars